# Why are Cuda kernels annotated with `__global__` instead of `__kernel__`

Tags: cuda

Actually, the title already is the full question.
Why did Nvidia decide to call its GPU entry functions *kernels*, but in Cuda they must be annotated with `__global__` instead of `__kernel__`?

Comment: I would recommend rephrasing this question entirely, so it fits the answer you've been given. changing a few words isn't gonna do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is to separate the entity (kernel) and its scope or location.

There three types of the functions which relate to your question:

1. `__device__` functions can be called only from the device, and it is
   executed only in the device.
2. `__global__` functions can be called
   from the host, and it is executed in the device.
3. `__host__`
   functions run on the host, called from the host.

If they named functions scope `__kernel__`, it would be impossible to distinguish them in the way they are separated above.

The `__global__` here means "in space shared between host and device" and in these terms in "global area between them".

Comment: Sounds a little bit reasonable, but with this argumentation `__global__` functions should be callable both from host and device.

Comment: @tomsch They are. Take a look at the `mandelbrot_block_k` function in this example of dynamic parallelism in NVIDIA's developer blog: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/introduction-cuda-dynamic-parallelism/

Comment: In this context "global" means "in space shared between host and device" and in these terms in "global area between them" (updated the answer). Well, of course, it is a kind of NVIDIA's choice for naming. Other API/framework use different naming. For example, OpenCL uses `__kernel` instead of `__global__` , right as you suggested.

Comment: @njuffa I know about such examples. But, this feature was only added in Cuda 5.0. Before that it was not possible and the name `__global__` was already in use with Cuda 5.0. Maybe, the planned that feature from the very beginning.